# Div Height not working with Dynamic Content IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a script that loads google charts api information into a div. The div has a fixed height and a scroll property. However, when the table from google loads, it overflows the div (see image below). This is on IE 8 in compatibility mode, and the css is as follows:

```
div.dashwrapper .no_overflow{overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; height: 300px;}
```

Here is what it looks like in IE8 (Blue outline is from developer tools, it outlines the height of the div though)
[image: Dynamic content ignoring height constraint]

And this is what it looks like in Firefox (how it should look)
[image: Firefox output]

Here is the HTML/Javascript for it:

```
<script>
var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chain_info_this_year'));
    table.draw(data , {showRowNumber: true});

    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Store Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Chain');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Intakes <?php echo date("F");?>');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ships <?php echo date("F");?>');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Intakes <?php echo date("Y");?>');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ships <?php echo date("Y");?>');
    data.addRows([
                <?php 
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($store_info); $i++)
                {
                    
                    if ($i <count($store_info) - 1)
                        echo "['" . str_replace("'", '',$store_info[$i]['chain']) . "', '" . str_replace("'", '', $store_info[$i]['store']). "', "  . $store_info[$i]['intakes_this_month'] . "," 
                            . $store_info[$i]['ships_this_month'] . "," . $store_info[$i]['intakes_this_year'] . "," . $store_info[$i]['ships_this_year'] . "],";   
                    else 
                        echo "['" . str_replace("'", '',$store_info[$i]['chain']) . "', '" . str_replace("'", '', $store_info[$i]['store']). "', "  . $store_info[$i]['intakes_this_month'] . "," 
                                . $store_info[$i]['ships_this_month'] . "," . $store_info[$i]['intakes_this_year'] . "," . $store_info[$i]['ships_this_year'] . "]";
                }
                ?>
                ]);
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('store_info'));
    table.draw(data , {showRowNumber: true});

    </script>
    <div class='dash_row no_overflow'>
    <div class='dash_mod full_width'>
        <div class='title'>Store Information <span class='small_text space_left'><a style='cursor: pointer' onclick = "expand();">Show All</a></span></div>
        <div class='mod_content'><span id='store_info'></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is more html, but this is relevant stuff. The dash_row div is inside dashwrapper though, just to clarify.

UPDATE: JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/qKzLf/

Comment: also give the html code please

Comment: Would just an "overflow: hidden;" work on the containing div?

Comment: A code exemple please. Use http://jsfiddle.net/ for example

Comment: Thanks for the help, HTML is added. @Mike, overflow:hidden won't work because I need to be able to scroll through the entire table. It has to do with IE ignoring height properties on dynamically generated content. For example, the div is created with a set height, but then the data from the google charts api is inserted and the height is ignored.

Comment: Here is an example, the Charts api isn't working in fiddle, I will have to check and make sure I copied everything in a litle bit. This is pretty close though. http://jsfiddle.net/qKzLf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found to this was to use JQuery to reset the css height property after the content loads. This is because, apparently, IE 8 in compatibility mode renders the css, then ignores it with dynamic content.